# Are multiple configurations possible for spark jobs?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, cluster-computing, bigdata

Suppose I have PCs as follows

1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9

Now suppose I have two spark jobs A and B. A job generates data C which B takes as input. For getting C I need to have cluster like this

cluster 1: master: 1, slaves: 2 3

cluster 2: master: 4, slaves: 5 6

cluster 3: master: 7, slaves: 8 9

For B job I need to have cluster like this:

cluster 4: master: 4, slaves: 1 7

How can I set up clusters like this, where same pc may belong to different cluster at different times and can become master/slave?

Also most importantly even if configuration like this is possible, then what is the best practice for coding such spark application so that we wouldn't need separate spark application for job A and B?

Comment: I don't understand the question exactly, but you can submit Spark jobs to different clusters via the `--master` argument

Comment: Regarding not needing two applications, you can stop and start a new SparkContext within one application

Comment: @cricket_007 when submitting spark job to a master, I need to have spark cluster ready. But I want to change the cluster dynamically so that one portion of code can run on some PCs on the cluster and for other portion it can run on other PCS on the cluster. Master and slaves have to charge accordingly. Is it possible?

Comment: SparkContext will run same PCs on the preconfigured cluster. I need to change cluster configuration. Can it be done in one application?

Comment: I don't know what execution engine you're using... YARN, Mesos, or Standalone? If the first two, that's configured there, not within Spark. Also master and slave processes on one machine seems like a bad idea

Comment: @cricket_007 I am using Standalone for now.

Comment: Okay, then, well I'm still under the impression that you must manually reconfigure the master and slaves. I doubt an executor process could do that.

Comment: That is, unless you place SSH commands in between all the Spark code that'll re-establish a cluster, but that's somewhat broad to answer here

Answer (score -1):

I will assume you're running your spark jobs on top of a YARN/MapReduce2 + HDFS cluster.

To do what you want you don't need more than one cluster, the orchestration level you want can be achieved using [Apache Oozie](http://oozie.apache.org/) to write a workflow (Like in this case, run A then run B with A's output).

On another similar topic, if you´re afraid about the resources consumed by each job, you can create queues in YARN and submit each job to a different queue, by doing this you can ensure they all get the amount of resources you want and they can be ran concurrently.

Finally, if you submit those jobs in `--deploy-mode cluster`and `--master yarn`, you don´t have to worry about masters and slaves, since the `spark driver` and the `spark context` will be kept distributed in the cluster.